# Brew keg for tcl-tk doesn't install symlink for libtcl

Tags: tcl, homebrew

I install Homebrew tcl-tk on an M1 Mac; it's keg-only (because of fears about macOS's deprecated 8.5), but I don't think that's the problem.

What happens is, `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/tcl-tk/lib` only has `libtcl8.6.dylib`, `libtk8.6.dylib`, but I was expecting symbolic links e.g. `libtcl.dylib -> libtcl8.dylib -> libtcl.8.6.dylib`. This means that I have to link using e.g. `-ltcl8.6` instead of `-ltcl`.

Of course, I could just live with this - the chance of a Tcl/Tk 9 is probably pretty remote! (8.7 alpha is on the stocks)

Any workarounds?

Comment: The chance of a Tcl 9 isn't very remote! The current planned feature freeze for 8.7 and 9.0 is a bit over a month away...

Comment: I consider it good practice to link against a specific Tcl version `-ltcl8.6`, also when using stubs (this makes the linked version the minimum Tcl version required). Other than that, whether "keg" or not, there is no reason not provide those symlinks as part of the brew recipe (the MacPort Tcl port also provides for a symlink).